Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected url to equal url in Cypress
Trying log in after 2fa, is not possible log in with Cypress. It gives the following error:
Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected url to equal url.

How can I handle this issue?
it("Login", () => {
    cy.visit("/login");

    cy.get("[name=email]").type("example@com"); 
    cy.get("[name=password]").type("example!");
    cy.get("button[type=submit]").click();

    cy.location("pathname").should("equal", "/two-fa");

    // Enter two-factor authentication code
    cy.get('.code_digits.d-flex [type=number]').each(($el, index, $list) => {
      cy.wrap($el).type(index + 1);
    });

    cy.wait(5000); //
    cy.url().should("eq", "/"); 
      }); 
    });


"expected url to equal url in Cypress" error happens when the you try to access the URL XYZ but the browser (usually due a redirect) goes to the URL TUV. To debug it, we need to know what URL you are trying to land and which URL you are actually landing. Can you share this info, possibly showing some screen shots?

Jou are checking the entire url to be equal "/". That is unlikely to happen. Url is more like https://site.domain.com/path

This can happen due to several reasons, including asynchronous behavior or delays in the application.
To handle this issue effectively, you can adjust your test to wait for the URL to change to / after entering the two-factor authentication code.
it("Login with Two-Factor Authentication", () => {
  cy.visit("/login");

  cy.get("[name=email]").type("example@com"); 
  cy.get("[name=password]").type("example!");
  cy.get("button[type=submit]").click();
  cy.location("pathname").should("equal", "/two-fa");

  // Enter two-factor authentication code
  cy.get('.code_digits.d-flex [type=number]').each(($el, index, $list) => {
    cy.wrap($el).type(index + 1);
  });
  cy.get("button[type=submit]").click();

  // Wait for the URL to change to "/"
  cy.url().should("eq", Cypress.config().baseUrl + "/"); 
});


